# How to enhance parallelism in a python client for elasticsearch?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, parallel-processing, pyes

I am new to elasticsearch and I need to optimize a python client to do the search/indexing on a elasticsearch cluster. It seems to me that the bottleneck is the client itself, and that elasticsearch can handle more queries. 
I would like to know how I can make my program more optimal to enhance performance. Should I use multi-processing or multi-threading or there is a more elegant way to do the work. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your ES server can easily handle multiple request you can use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) in order to run multiple queries concurrently.

As the operation is mainly IO driven, using threads should be enough.

Comment: Apache Spark has a Python interface to ES.  There is a tutorial on it at http://blog.qbox.io/building-an-elasticsearch-index-with-python and http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsearch-in-apache-spark-python.